# How to set sonar properties in case I have multiple subdirectories of target folder in same project

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to enable sonarqube for my project but the problem is that I just want to scan through my all .class files generated in the target folder.
How can I configure the sonar properties to scan through the whole project?
I can configure through comma but there are a lot of projects residing in one single module.
Using sonarqube version-8.4.2
for eg my project structure is -

Main Project(P1) -
Sub Project(P12)
sub project(P121)
sub project(P121)
Sub Project(P13)
Sub Project(P14)
sub project(P121)
sub project(P121)
Sub Project(P15)

assume that each respective project generates the target folder by maven.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you can use the following sonar properties to scan the java binaries:

```
sonar.java.binaries=**/* or sonar.java.binaries=**/*.class
sonar.sources=src/
```

Also, you can exclude the files which you don’t want to scan, using the `sonar.exclusions` sonar properties. Example.

```
sonar.exclusions=**/*.java
```

Answer (score 0):

When you said "configure through comma", that implies that you know that you can specify multiple directories, and you probably already knew the two properties you need to set (listed in @souravatta's answer).

What I read from your question is that you don't want to list all of those directories.

The way I see it, you have two choices:

- Manually specifying all the paths to each subproject
- Producing separate SonarQube scans for each subproject

Obviously, the second choice would solve your first problem, but it completely changes other aspects.  If each of those subprojects represents individual artifacts that otherwise could stand alone, then you really should consider them separately.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was looking for some generic change. and I have almost 33 projects inside my one component so I don't know how the SonarQube dashboard will provide us the consolidated report for separate SonarQube scan.